# Search by multiple values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can i make my search engine accept inputs more than one which are seperated by comma?

[image]

This is my **index.view**:

```
<p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
    {
    <b>Search by:</b> @Html.RadioButton("searchby", "ItemID", true)<text>Item Id</text>   
    <br />
    @Html.TextBox("search") <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    }
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            ItemID
        </th>
        <th>
            Item name
        </th>
    </tr>
    @if (Model.Count() == 0)
    {
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">no item id found.</td>
        </tr>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemid)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.itemname)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
        <caption>Total @Html.Encode(Model.Count()) item found.</caption>
    }
</table>
```

And this is my **homecontroller.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using itemdb.Models;

namespace itemdb.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private mydbEntities db = new mydbEntities();

    public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBy) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            if (searchBy == "itemid")
            {
                return View(db.itemlist.Where(x => x.items == search).ToList());
            }
        else
        {
            return View(db.itemlist.Take(0));
        }
    } 
}
}
```

Comment: [String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchBy, string search)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchBy) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            string[] items = search.Split(new Char[] {','});
            if (searchBy == "itemid")
            {
                return View(db.itemlist.Where(x => items.Contains(x.items)).ToList());
            }
        else
        {
            return View(db.itemlist.Take(0));
        }
    }
```